# Simplify else if statements in JS for a prompt to code?

Tags: javascript

How do I simplify else if statements? I want the code to be able to run a bunch of code based on the users input, such as bring to link for some of them, so I am not looking for

```
alert (prompt)
```

BELOW IS AN EXAMPLE

```
var prompt = prompt ("Test");

if (prompt == "test1"){
alert ("test1")
}

else if (prompt == "Test2"){
alert ("test2")
}

else if (prompt == "Test3"){
alert ("Test3")
}
```

Is there a way to stop copy pasting the else if statements and shorten the code? Sorry. Im a bit newbie.

Comment: Give a bit more context about what you're actually trying to achieve with that code please.

Comment: If you're example is exact to the scenario you have, then `if (prompt) { alert(prompt); }` should simplify it quite a bit. I assume that's not actually the case though.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into switch statements? It may provide cleaner code and possibly better speed if you have a lot of possibilities (more than 5) for the prompt var.

```
var prompt = "Test1"
switch(prompt) {
    case "Test1":
        alert(prompt)
        break;
    case "Test2":
        alert(prompt)
        break;
    default:
        alert(prompt)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably need more context here, depending on the number of cases you could possibly make this cleaner by

```
const availablePrompts = [“Test1”, “Test2”...]

if(availablePrompts.includes(prompt)) { 
  alert(prompt)
} else {
 \\ action when the prompt is not valid 
}
```

Of course this assumes you are actually trying to run the same function for each prompt. If there are only a few cases  it probably isn’t worth trying to shorten/optimize, if there are 5-10, probably a switch statement, and if there are more than 10ish there could potentially just be a better way to structure your logic so that it is more generalizable.

Comment: @Jonathan Harvey if you recently registered and [Jonathan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/197127/jonathan) is your unregistered account, you can request a merge via the [contact](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom left corner of the page.